# uso de los vectores

Tags: c++

Necesito registrar una cantidad de personas ingresadas por el usuario,buscarlas y luego mostrarlas,pero no se como buscar esa información y como mostrarla.
Hice una funcion `buscar_datos` y `mostrar_datos`.

```
void ingresar_datos(){
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de usuarios que desea registrar"<<endl;
    cin>>repetir;system("cls");

    for( x=0;x<repetir;x++){
      cout<<"\tINGRESE LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO:"<<endl;
      cout<<"1.-Ingrese el Nombre: ";
      cin.getline( per[x].nombre,200);

      cout<<"2.-Ingrese el Apellido: ";
      cin>>per[x].apellido;

      cout<<"3.-Ingrese el codigo del numero de telefono: ";
      cin>>per[x].telefono;

      if(per[x].telefono==a||per[x].telefono==b||per[x].telefono==c||per[x].telefono==d||per[x].telefono==e){
        cout<<"3.1-Ingrese el resto del numero de telefono: ";
        cin>>per[x].telefono2;  
      }else{
        cout<<"ERROR - INGRESO UN CODIGO INCORRECTO"<<endl;
        exit(1);
      }

      cout<<"4.-Ingrese el codigo del numero Celular: ";
      cin>>per[x].celular;            

      if(per[x].celular==f||per[x].celular==g||per[x].celular==h||per[x].celular==i||per[x].celular==j){
        cout<<"4.1.-Ingrese el resto del numero: ";
        cin>>per[x].celular2;   
      }else{
        cout<<"ERROR - INGRESO UN CODIGO INCORRECTO"<<endl;
        exit(1);
      }

      cout<<"5.-Ingrese el correo electronico: ";
      cin>>per[x].correo;
      cout<<"6.-Ingrese la Ciudad: ";
      cin>>per[x].ciudad;   
      cout<<"7.-Ingrese el Pais: ";
      cin>>per[x].pais;

      do {                                          
        cout<<"\tSE HAN CARGADO LOS DATOS CORRECTAMENTE"<<endl;
      }while(per[x].pais == "venezuela");   
    }
  }
```

Comment: ¿ Cual es el problema ? ¿ Donde están esas funciones `buscar_datos` y `mostrar_datos` ? ¿ Que es `per[]` ?

Comment: Yo echaría un vistazo a la forma que tiene C++ de hacer "List" como en java, son muy útiles para hacer búsquedas, insertar y extraer elementos

Comment: Expresiones como esta: `cin>>repetir;system("cls");` dejaron de usarse hace más de 20 años (por suerte), pero también dices "soy nuevo en programación"; yo creo que deberías cambiar de libro.

Comment: Hola @Luis, ¿encontraste la solución al final? Si no, deberías añadir la información que falta para ayudar a otros usuarios y que puedan asistir con este problema.